# In react-jsonschema-form, what uiSchema changes all booleans to be radio buttons?

Tags: react-jsonschema-forms

In react-jsonschema-form, what uiSchema changes all booleans on a form to display as radio buttons?

Answer (score 1):

By default boolean are checkboxes but you can use the radio [Alternative Widgets](https://github.com/mozilla-services/react-jsonschema-form/blob/master/README.md#alternative-widgets) . You will probably have to set it for each boolean field

Answer (score 1):

you can use  **"ui:widget": "radio"** for radio button and by default its as select so its use checkboxes as a default boolean value item widget.

Comment: I think this should be a comment not an answer.